# MediaElement MediaFailed error 3100 IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: windows-phone, mediaelement, isolatedstoragefile

I receive mp3 files from web service and save them to **isolated storage**. The problem is that some of that files are playing fine in MediaElement, another - no (MediaFailed 3100 error: Error occured).

I'm using `MediaElement.setSource(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream)` method.

The most confusion about the problem - **all those files play fine on wp7 phones**, but when I use wp8 phone problem occurs.

I tried to recompile project to wp8 only, changed Capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml - but this not helped.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Project sample: http://sdrv.ms/19ENcHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add extension to filename.